# Programmable delay line IC

Tags: xilinx, delay, programmable-logic, line

I'm currently redesigning a delay line circuit. It is implemented on a Xilinx CPLD IC. Minimum delay is about 200 ns and maximum 600 µs, which is enough range for my project. What I want to do is increase delay resolution from about 10 ns resolution to 2 ns or better. Do you know any digital delay ICs to replace Xilinx CPLD? Please consider that as a distance simulator. At the input there is a photodiode and at the output LED. So every nano second counts.

Now there is 100MHz clock, and I know that the simplest way is to replace it to 200MHz or more, but unfortunately this CPLD doesn't have PLL so I think that 200Mhz will be the limit. And in case of replacing it for different CPLD I thought about adding for ex MC10EP195 to increase resolution (MC10EP195 has 10ps step). What do you think about that?

Comment: Hi, mil! Welcome to the forum. Are you sure you need a whole IC for that? I mean, you can count MCU cycles for that, if you need a fixed value, you can do RC timer. Just wanna make sure you're not inventing a wheel

Comment: I think this sounds like an X-Y problem. What kind of signal are you delaying, and for what purpose? If you give us a better idea of what it is you're trying to accomplish, we can tell you more about how it's usually done. As it stands, this is either a "product recommendation" question or an "opinion" question, either of which would be off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail, with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Hi :) Please consider that as a distance simulator. At the input there is a photodiode and at the output LED. So every nano second counts.

Comment: What is your current clock rate? For 10ns, you need 100MHz, I assume it is generated internally via a PLL. For 2ns, you need to generate 500MHz clock (obviously, not the entire part has to be clocked that high, only the least significant part of the counter), so choose your part according to this requirement.

Comment: The 10EP195 will give you plenty of resolution (on the order of 10 ps), but keep in mind that its absolute accuracy is only on the order of +/- 20%. Is this good enough for your purposes?

Comment: Yes, now there is 100MHz clock, and I know that the simplest way is to replace it to 200MHz or more, but unfortunately this CPLD doesn't have PLL so I think that 200Mhz will be the limit. And in case of replacing int for different CPLD I thought about adding for ex MC10EP195 to increase resolution (MC10EP195 has 10ps step).

Comment: Please edit your question and add all this new information. Otherwise people have to piece together the full question from the comments. Thanks.